# Transforming type Int64Index into an integer index in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, type-conversion

I'm quite new with python, however, I have to accomplish some assignment and I am struggling now on a problem. I try to get the index of the element in a table A when some other parameter from this table A corresponds to a value in a list B. The table A also already contains a column `"index"` where all elements are numerated from 0 till the end. Moreover, the values in `tableA.parameter1` and listB can coincide only once, multiple matches are not possible. So to derive the necessary index I use a line

```
t=tableA.index[tableA.parameter1==listB[numberObservation]]
```

However, what I get as a result is something like:

```
t Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```

If I use the variable t in this format Int64Index, it doesn't suit for the further code I have to work with. Actually, I need only 2 as an integer number, without all this redundant rest.

Can somebody please help me to circumvent my problem? I am in total despair and would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What package is giving you `Int64Index`? This looks vaguely `numpy`-ish, but `numpy` arrays define `__index__` so a single element array of integer values will seamlessly operate as indices for sequence lookup.

Regardless, assuming `t` is supposed to be exactly one value, and it's a sequence type itself, you can just do:

```
t, = tableA.index[tableA.parameter1==listB[numberObservation]]
```

That trailing comma changes the line from straight assignment to iterable unpacking; it expects the right hand side to produce an iterable with exactly one value, and that one value is unpacked into `t`. If the iterable has 0 or 2+ values, you'll get a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 6):

Try .tolist()

```
t=tableA.index[tableA.parameter1==listB[numberObservation]].tolist()
```

This should return

```
t = [2]
```

a list "without all the redundant rest" :)

Comment: hi! I have tested your solution as well, thanks for your help. Especially it is useful if I have more than one match. Then **t** as a list should provide a good solution. However, I still have one problem. When I run your code, I get the error message 'Invalid frame count (= tableA.index[tableA.parameter1==listB])'. Moreover, when I debug the code and run only the command in IPython console without assigning the result to the variable - it works... Do you have any idea where the problem could be?

Comment: I haven't faced the error 'Invalid frame count' with pandas. Is it possible for you to post a complete test program, with only the important details?